# How to make a certain pattern or algorithm when entering staff id in login form?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make a login form with an input for Staff ID, Password, and submit. For say, software has a serial # that will only be accepted if it matches the pattern or format of the serial that is required for the software. How would I do that? I want it to have a thumbnail that will popup and tell you that is is not the proper format kind of like `required` does when you put in in the `input` tag. I want to also be able to possibly style the thumbnail as well, in order to make it match the UI of the site.

html form:

```
<section name="LoginSection" id="LoginSection" class="LoginSection">
  <div name="LoginHeader" id="LoginHeader" class="LoginHeader">
    <center><h3>Staff Login</h3></center>
  </div>
  <form name="LoginForm" id="LoginForm" class="LoginForm" action="">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Staff Identification Number" name="StaffInput" id="StaffInput" class="StaffInput" required />
    <input type="password" placeholder="Staff Login Password" name="StaffPass" id="StaffPass" class="StaffPass" required />
    <center><input type="submit" value=" Submit " name="Submit" id="Submit" class="Submit" /></center>
  </form>
</section>
```

Comment: thanks a lot for helping us with the question. Please enlighten us with your code as well.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the comment give me a minutes please.

Comment: You guys could also go to Anonymous-Legion.com so you can see what the login section looks like.

Comment: You can put a *blur* listener on the fields or *submit* listener on the form and do validation of values when it fires. The placeholder attribute should not be used to replace a label.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try more on HTML5 thing:

```
<input type="tel" name="mobileno" pattern="[789][0-9]{9}" required title="Enter Mobileno in correct format"/>
```

Or if you want it using Javascript something like :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function login()
    {    

        if(document.loginFrm.mobileno.value.length==0 )
        {
        alert('Enter MobileNo please');
            document.loginFrm.mobileno.focus()  
        }   
        //return false
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, but is there any other way that I can style the little thumbnail thing that pops up with css, in order to make it match my dark flat ui?

Comment: you can try Messi.js for some nice alerts and edit the CSS there

Answer (score 0):

i think you can get your imagination for combination some html css and php. or with bootstrap design ?

for example :

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if($_POST['name'] == NULL && $_POST['pass'] == NULL){
      echo'<div class="login">
              <span> It didn't work ! </span>
           </div>';
    }
  }
```

hehe i always do that if i want to combine skill with css html and php :)

You can see my update answare with jquery :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#button').click(function(){
      if($('#txt-name').val() == '' && $('#txt-pwd').val() == ''){
         alert('It didn't work');
      }
   });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but I was looking for more of a javascript thing. Any other suggestions?